# How OneSignal decides which p12 file to use (development or distribution)?

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

While sending notification if there are two p12 files (development and Distribution) then how onesignal decides which one to use?

Answer (score 1):

OneSignal's SDK checks the provisioning profile to find the release mode used while building the app that it uploads to the server when registering a new user/player.

> [ @"test_type" => @(release_mode)]

The **release_mode** is a OneSignal typedef **UIApplicationReleaseMode** returned by the **OneSignalMobileProvision** singleton while parsing the provisioning profile.

Check: [+ OneSignalMobileProvision releaseMode](http://pastebin.com/KxxcdZbq)

Answer (score 0):

Based on OneSignal's documentation:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions-1

*Make sure you are using the latest SDK as it will automatically detect the push environment so this way our back end can use the correct push certificate for your device.*

It will automatically use the correct one.

Comment: what if two p12 files are there?